# Run jar file as windows service automatically on system startup without using licensed tools

Tags: java, jar, windows-services, system, startup

My Java application contains a simple `HelloWorld` class. I have extracted the jar file of my Java application and want to run that jar file automatically on system startup.

It should appear in `Control Panel->Administrative tools->Services` and also automatically run when the computer starts.

I am not considering the solution of using third party/licensed tools here.

Answer (score 0):

a simple free solution is [JavaExe](http://devwizard.free.fr/).